# The type or namespace name 'oracle' could not be found error

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I am building C# Console Application to connect with database and do simple query.

But when I debug program, I get this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Oracle' could not be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? )
```

I need to use:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
```

I have downloaded from Oracle site ODAC pack. Inside I have Install batch file ( i have used it ) but nothing still.

I am using MS VS2012 Express for Windows Desktop.

What file should I include when adding a reference ?

Comment: Does "Used it" include adding the Oracle dll to your project references?

Comment: No, I executed it. Should I manually copy some files more ?

Comment: Expand your project, right click on references and check that you have added the Oracle client dll to your project

Comment: alternatively use the NuGet Package Manager to get your dependency, i'm pretty sure MySQL is in there, by oracle itself

Comment: what if I using docker? Is nuget the solution?

Answer (score 5):

Agreed you need to reference :

```
 Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

You may need to be careful that you have the right Oracle client installed - if you have the 32bit one then you may need to force your app into 32 bit mode.

For distribution you may also want to include all the dependencies in your BIN folder - for 32bit that would look like :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the install location of the pack you downloaded there is

```
Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

which you should reference.
[Here is a guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/436023/Setting-up-Oracle-Database-for-NET-development) doing exactly that.

Comment: Also, make sure you are using a DLL compatible with the .net version of your project.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098563/oracle-managed-data-access-dll-upgrading-to-latest-version-causes-compile-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1