# Which Oracle drivers do I need for ASP.NET 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to install the correct Oracle drivers on my development machine. I'm creating an ASP.NET web site and every time I run I get an error saying that says "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client". I have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle drivers but have still had no luck. Can someone lead me to a link for the drivers I need based on my specs?

I'm using Windows 8 64-bit. The database is Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 - 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ODAC112021Xcopy_x64.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) might give you the dll's and client you'll need. Take a look at this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201066/1764737) for more detail about deployment of the application.