# Issue Connecting To Oracle Using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll when published to server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll to connect to oracle database from ASP.Net with .net framework 4 , it is working fine when checking locally . However when i publish it to webserver i am getting below error

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Oracle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Line 7:  using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

It seems that after publishing application is unable to find required dll however the dll is present in bin folder on server

Any idea what might be causing this issue

Also tried uploading dependency dlls to bin folder but still same issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name 'oracle' could not be found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200790/the-type-or-namespace-name-oracle-could-not-be-found-error)

Comment: Does not seems to be duplicate since provided thread references Oracle.DataAccess.dll instead of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client