# Oracle Managed Data Access DLL upgrading to latest version causes compile errors

Tags: c#, oracle, dll, visual-studio-2019

When I upgraded Oracle.ManagedDatabaseAccess.dll from v. 4.122.18.3 to v. 4.122.21.1 there are several compile errors, specifically:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Oracle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The reference has been added.  I initially used a version-specific folder, and thinking this could cause some sort of problem, I moved it to the exact same folder where the older DLL had been successfully referenced, and there was still the problem.

This is somewhat like [Similar Oracle problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200790/the-type-or-namespace-name-oracle-could-not-be-found-error), except that the linked post appears to be about Oracle.DataAccess.DLL whereas this is the managed version, Oracle.ManagedDataAcess.dll

I also have tried cleaning and "rebuild all" as well as unloading the problematic project in the solution and reloading it also, and neither helps.

As far as I can discern, both DLL's are 32-bit.

I am using Visual Studio 2019, a C#, asp.net context, and since the other Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll worked without special usage of a "register DLL" procedure, I'm not certain if that is needed or will help.

Is there any help for this situation?

Comment: The ODP.NET Managed Driver is independent from 32/64-Bit, this cannot be the problem. Note, assemblies installed in GAC takes always precedence over files copied to application folder. Check your GAC with `gacutil /l | findstr Oracle | sort`, perhaps the policy files are missing. The policy file direct to installed version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to use .net Version 4.6.2.  This locally built on my machine and everything worked.  We are not ready for this so I reverted to the previous DLL, but thanks.  Also, when changing .net versions, one sometimes has to load/unload projects, restart Visual studio, and make sure the saves of the project file actually "take".

Perhaps this Question and Answer will help someone else, someday.

Comment: According to [Developer's Guide - System Requriements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/InstallSystemRequirements.html#GUID-A6405CAD-C0E9-45E0-9C38-26B7ED214479) Version 4.122.21 requires even Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: You could mark it as the answer.